# Unresolvered reference: when I call the method of an instance from another activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to call the method of an instance of AuthActivity from MainActivity. However, I get an error.
AuthActivity contains a variable that lets you know if the user has already authenticated from this activity!

Unresolvered reference: checkIfUserAlreadyLogged()

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(applicationContext)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      
        if (AuthActivity.checkIfUserAlreadyLogged()) {
            return this.displayAuthWithFragment(AuthActivity.HOME_FRAGMENT)
        }

    }
 }
```

Here is my AuthActivity class:

```
package com.ksainthi.inance


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth by lazy {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)

    }


    fun checkIfUserAlreadyLogged(): Boolean {
        if (this.firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
 }
```

Comment: "I would like to call the method of an instance of AuthActivity from MainActivity" -- that is impractical. If these are that closely coupled, then perhaps they should be a single activity with two fragments or composables for the screens.

Comment: First, does `AuthActivity` even need to be an activity? If you just want a helper class for calling things on FirebaseAuth it wouldn't need to inherit from Activity. If you want to share code between components, don't put it in an Activity. Second, you are getting an error because you are attempting to call your function like it is a static method (`AuthActivity.someMethod`)

Comment: @TylerV 124 / 5 000
Résultats de traduction
Hello, how would you have done to call the method from an instance (With the instance context, not static)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have some code or state variables shared between Activities, they should not live in one of the activities. Activity instances are created and destroyed automatically as a part of the application lifecycle, so getting access to one Activity instance from a different Activity instance is not a feasible/reliable approach.

One way of sharing code between Activities in Kotlin is to make an object class, like this

```kotlin
object FirebaseHelper {

    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth by lazy {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }
    
    fun checkIfUserAlreadyLogged(): Boolean {
        return firebaseAuth.currentUser != null
    }
}
```

Then you can call `FirebaseHelper.checkIfUserAlreadyLogged()` from any activity